# Controller losing reference to button in Sencha-touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm having a problem with some code in a controller.  When I click the Back button it switches to a different view, however when I go back to the view, the click handler no longer works.

See below code....

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MyDetails', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    requires: [
        'TolMobile.view.MyDetails',        

        'Ext.field.Select',
        'Ext.field.DatePicker'
    ],

    config: {
        refs: {

        },

        control: {
            "#btnMyDetailsBack": {
                tap: 'onBackButton'
            }
        }
    },

    onBackButton: function () {        
        MyApp.app.switchMainView('MyApp.view.Home', {});
    }

});
```

The app class code:

```
switchMainView: function (newView, config) {
    if (this.currentView != false) {
        Ext.Viewport.remove(this.currentView);
    }

    this.currentView = Ext.create(newView, config);
    // animateActiveItem - TODO animation not working (but shows ok)
    Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(this.currentView, { type: 'slide', direction: 'right' })
}
```

Seems to now work with the following instead of the switchMainView() call.
This code is called on the button click within the home view controller and now the animations work AND the forward/back.  I'd really like to know WHY though...

```
 var detailsView = Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyDetails');   
            detailsView.setRecord(userRecord);
            Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(detailsView, { type: 'slide', direction: 'left' })
```

Comment: Why no use Ext.navigation.View which already handles the back button.

Comment: Also, I bet you have a warning in the console that looks like this one "Registering a component with a id (btnMyDetailsBack) which has already been used..."

Comment: I want to control exactly what goes in the toolbar though...dont seem to get a warning either...

Comment: @jaffa You can still put items in the navigation bar: just use `getNavigationBar().add()` on your `Ext.navigation.View` instance.

Comment: What do you mean 'I want to control exactly what goes in the toolbar though'. Is there things you want to prevent from going there or you'd like to add things to it ?

Comment: I thought the Navigation view was fixed with a back button but I was wrong.  I seem to have got this working please see above edit...but not sure WHY?